# Border-Image Outside of the Box-Model

Tags: html, border, css

I'm currently working on a portfolio project and I have a concept for the header but I am having difficult achieving it.

I want to make the bottom border of my header (and top border of my footer) look like it's a brush stroke. As seen in my photobucket link.

http://i568.photobucket.com/albums/ss130/Lovin_RainyNights/ScreenShot2014-09-29at50243PM.png

I created a border image to use but it's getting hidden in the box model since the headers background color is the same as the border. I changed the background color to black so it can easily be seen

http://i568.photobucket.com/albums/ss130/Lovin_RainyNights/ScreenShot2014-09-29at50110PM.png

So what I would like to know is: Is there a way to get the border image to border the outside, not the inside of the header?

This is the code I have

HTML

```
<header>
    <h1>My Name</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span id="current">Projects</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header{
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-image: url("border.png") 0 0 33 0;
}
h1{
    float: left;
}
nav{
    text-align: right;
}
nav li{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border-image-outset property specifies the amount by which the border image area extends beyond the border box.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image-outset.asp

```
div {
    border-image-source: url(border.png);
    border-image-outset: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should not do it. You can wrap your `footer` into a `bordered-footer` and add the `border` to the `borderedfooter`. In general, the `border` is part of a tag. You can set `border-image-outset` as @bpettijohn pointed out, but I think that would be confusing later when you are already used to the standard meaning of `border`.